# Problems understanding: $\Sigma \vdash \theta \text{ iff }\Sigma \vdash \forall x \theta$

Tags: logic, intuition

> I'm trying to make sense of a theorem I came across recently:
>
> $$\Sigma \vdash \theta  \text{ iff }\Sigma \vdash \forall x \theta$$

Say $\theta$ is $(x=1)$, then we have $\Sigma \vdash (x=1)\text{ iff }\Sigma \vdash \forall x (x=1)$.

Well, $\Sigma \vdash \theta \Rightarrow \Sigma \models \theta$, which means for every structure $(\Bbb A)$ with universe $(A)$ and every assignment function $(s)$:
$$(\forall \Bbb A)(\forall s)(\Bbb A \models \Sigma[s] \Rightarrow \Bbb A \models \theta[s])$$
and
$$(\forall \Bbb A)(\forall s)(\forall a \in A)(\Bbb A \models \theta[s(x|a)])$$
where $s(x|a)(v) = \{s(v) \text{ if v is not x}, a \text{ if v is x}\}$.

But then doesn't this mean that with ANY structure and ANY universe associated with it and EVERY assignment function that every $x$ is $1$?

Comment: You have $\Sigma\vDash \theta$ means **every** structure that satisfy $\Sigma$ also satisfy $\theta$, so yes, it does mean that "with ANY structure and ANY universe associated with it(I assume you mean $\mathbb A\vDash\Sigma$ in this part) and EVERY assignment function that every $x$ is $1$"

Comment: See [Universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization#Generalization_with_hypotheses) : the theorem holds provided that $x$ is not free in $\Sigma$.

Comment: The intuition is : if $\theta$ holds, **without any assumptions on** $x$ [this is the gist of the proviso : "$x$ not free in $\Sigma$"], for $x$ whatever, then it holds of every $x$.

Comment: See the post [Why does universal generalization work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889107/why-does-universal-generalization-work-the-rule-of-inference) and also the post [How does Universal Generalization agree with facts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468781/how-does-universal-generalization-agree-with-facts)

Comment: See also [I don't get how “universal generalization” works?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767331/i-dont-get-how-universal-generalization-works-is-my-understanding-of-ui-ei)

Comment: I think I see now.  It's ASSUMING that the structure satisfies $\Sigma$ then this is true, not just any structure.

Comment: Yes, correct. $\theta$ is true in every structure that satisfies the "axioms" in $\Sigma$.

Comment: Consider as $\Sigma$ the set of first-order Peano axioms. The proviso on $x$ not free prevents deriving the fallacious $\forall x (x=1)$ simply because we cannot prove $(x=1)$ (the logic is sound and it is not true that $\mathbb N \vDash (x=1)$).